# Moto G stuck on the screen "Warning bootloader unlocked"

Tags: charging, boot, fastboot, bootloader, motorola-moto-g2

I'm trying to solve a problem that is affecting a **Moto G 2014 XT1069** device. What has happened is that the device did shutdown, then when trying to power it up again, it stayed stuck on the Motorola logo for some time. Another person trying to help, said that it was needed to format the cellphone and rebooted into recovery mode. The point is that when trying to factory reset an error appeared.

This person then said that the device was bricked and needed to do something to correct it. Then using fastboot through a computer, I don't know what she did but the situation got somehow worse.

The first thing is that she unlocked the bootloader. But after all the procedure what happens is that when the device powered up, it just got stuck in a screen with a message **WARNING BOOTLOADER UNLOCKED** and it *doesn't progress any further*.

On that same screen it is possible, by pressing **PWR** + **VOL DWN** to access the bootloader, but even if we select "Normal Powerup" or "Recovery", the device just gets back to the screen **WARNING BOOTLOADER UNLOCKED** and nothing more happens.

Furthermore, it seems that the battery became somehow "mad". After a *quite long* time interval charging, the device got to 29% of battery and after just a few minutes trying to correct all this mess, the battery got to 6%.

I don't know what they did and how all of this happened.

How can I fix this mess? How can I make the cellphone boot and make everything right again?

If possible I want to avoid flashing the factory image for the reason that I don't have access to the image from the official source and I feel quite uneasy to get from one untrusted source, since it might compromise confidential data.

What can I do to solve this? I believe there has to be a way to correct all of this.

Comment: At this point you need to flash the factory image, check XDA's area for your device (Moto G 2014) for the specific model (XTxxxx) and fastboot flash the appropriate factory image. The fact your bootloader is unlocked is NOT the problem, in fact, if you locked or relocked at this point your device would likely be permanently bricked.

Comment: @acejavelin, thanks very much for the advice. As you can imagine I'm new to these aspects of android, so any help is appreciated! I wanted to just bring the device to the prior state. The factory images that I've seem many people talking about  are obtained from trusted/official sources? In that case, how can I actually to this fastboot flash to recover the device?

Comment: @acejavelin, if I just do the usual factory reset, instead of this fastboot flash, could it work? Or if I do this I can make the situation worse?

Comment: You can try a factory reset, start recovery from the bootloader and when you see the Android with "No Command" displayed, press PWR+VOL UP to get to the menu and select Factory Reset, and let it boot. Remember that first boot can exceed 20 minutes! If that fails, look for an "official firmware" thread on XDA for your device, it will be a zip that contains several files and they digitally signed, so you as long as you have the correct device and follow the process, you can't really harm your device. This is more common than you think and we do this all the time, people will help if you ask.

Comment: Thanks for all the aid @acejavelin. I'll try the factory reset first. I've searched on XDA and found this (http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g-2014/general/firmware-retbrxt10695-0-2lxb22-46-28-zip-t3031891). The device is indeed XT1069 and the language is really PT-BR, so *I think* this is what you're talking about. My only concern is: isn't there a risk that the image has been tempered with with spyware-like or virus-like software that might capture confidential data? I became worried since this is distributed on Mega and not an official source.

Comment: There is always a chance... But the image parts are digitally signed. You can request a specific build from Moto, years ago I would say you'd have it a couple days, but some users are reporting it can take weeks if at all. You could always flash TWRP and a custom ROM instead.

Comment: @acejavelin, I was going to try the factory reset but the following happened: the device directly goes to the WARNING BOOTLOADER UNLOCKED screen. It doesn't shutdown, unless the batery ends. If I try to charge it, it automatically starts and goes to that screen. On that screen I used PWR + VOL DOWN and entered in fastboot mode. I tried the option "Recovery", but all the options get back to the warning screen and nothing else happens. If on the fastboot screen I wait and do nothing it gets to the no command screen. Do you think there's a way I can get into factory reset without need to flash?

Comment: I've found a way to do a hard reset via fastboot. The suggested commands are: erase modemst1, erase modemst2, erase cache, erase userdata, reboot. If I try this, can the device be permanently damaged? Or the worse it can happen is that it will stay the same?

Comment: no need to erase modems but the rest is fine

Answer (score 0):

Bootloader is a bit of code that tells your device's OS how to boot up? Does the phone boot in fastboot mode? If so you can tape `fastboot oem lock` or an alternatie that works on many motorola: `fastboot oem lock begin` this should relock the bootloader.

To boot in fastboot mode: Turn off your phone and then press and hold the Volume Down + Power buttons simultaneously for a few seconds.

If the above dont work, you'll need simply to flash the stock firmware first and then get in fastbootmode and tape`fastboot oem lock`

This [thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2575586) on XDA Developers will explain more in details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @esQmo, this fastboot mode is the way we boot to wipe the system? In that case, I must boot in fastboot mode and then where should I type this "fastboot oem lock"? Thanks again for the aid!

Comment: @user1620696 Be very careful, if you lock the bootloader in this state you will likely have a permanently bricked device. The bootloader is now unlocked, your options are open. If you look on XDA in the area for your specific device, you can find the factory images and how to flash them.

Comment: OP please read carefully what @acejavelin commented **twice**